# Ruby on Rails - Can I modify the value of an attribute before it is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, attributes

Let's say I have this model named *Product* with a field named *brand*. Suppose the values of *brand* are stored in the format *this_is_a_brand*. Can I define a method in the model (or anywhere else) that allows me to modify the value of *brand* before it is called. For example, if I call *@product.brand*, I want to get *This is a Brand*, instead of *this_is_a_brand*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would recommend using the square bracket syntax (`[]` and `[]=`) instead of `read_attribute` and `write_attribute`. The square bracket syntax is shorter and [designed to wrap the **protected** read/write_attribute methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M001375).

```
def brand
  original = self[:brand]
  transform(original)
end

def brand=(b)
  self[:brand] = reverse_transform(b)
end
```

Answer (score 9):

Rather than accessing @attributes directly, you should use `read_attribute` and `write_attribute`:

```
def brand
  b = read_attribute(:brand) 
  b && b.transform_in_some_way
end

def brand=(b)
  b && b.transform_in_some_way
  write_attribute(:brand, b)
end
```

Comment: What does the idiom b && b.transform_in_some_way mean?

Comment: And why is it better to use those methods?

Comment: For the other ppl not getting it: b && b.... is a common Ruby idiom. what's after the && is only executed if b is not nil. See also the andand gem for the same functionality: b.andand.transform_in_some_way

Answer (score 1):

As the last answer was posted 7 years ago, I'll contribute what the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) currently suggests.

```
def brand
  super.humanize
end
```

[Humanize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-humanize) turns 'this_is_a_brand' to 'This is a brand'

Answer (score 0):

In your model you can override the method call `brand`.

```
def brand
#code to modify the value that is stored in brand
return modified_brand
end
```

This will allow it to be stored as this_is_a_brand.  But, it will be returned as "this is a brand".

Comment: Ok, I got it. Attributes are stored in @attributes so I can just call @attributes['brand'] inside the method. Thanks for your help.